# two ajax requests in a non existent only appended div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been working on a 9gag like page. I tried to integrate a voting system which has been made by another guy, because I'm not really familiar with AJAX requests, and it just doesn't want to work.

My index.php loads five posts from the mySQL database then it appends them to the main div. After you scroll down it appends five more etc. This is done by an AJAX request which works like a charm.

When I append it to the div by AJAX, I also append some variables in the div so I can then use it for another AJAX request and this is where the problem occurs. It just doesn't do any AJAX requests. After an hour of debugging I've come to question whether one can append some data to a div, which doesn't exist in the original index.php and then run AJAX requests with it.

I won't post the pagination.js and it's stuff here because it works, I'm only going to post the ajax.php request where it could go wrong:

```
    <?php
    include 'config/connection.php';
    $db = "test";
    $table = "posts";

    $offset = is_numeric($_POST['offset']) ? $_POST['offset'] : die();
    $postnumbers = is_numeric($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : die();

    $run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $db.$table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    echo "      <article>\n";
    echo "          <div id='title'><h1>".utf8_encode($row['title'])."</h1></div>\n";
    echo "          <div id='image'><img src='posts/".$row['dDate']."/".$row['image']."'></div>\n";
    echo "          <div id='text' class='item' data-postid='".$row['id']."' data-score='".$row['vote']."'>\n";
    echo "              <p>Beküldte: ".$row['postedBy']."\n";
    echo "              <div class='vote-span'><!-- voting-->\n";
    echo "                  <div class='vote' data-action='up' title='Vote up'>\n";
    echo "                      <i class='icon-chevron-up'></i>\n";
    echo "                  </div><!--vote up-->\n";
    echo "                  <div class='vote-score'>".$row['vote']."</div>\n";
    echo "                  <div class='vote' data-action='down' title='Vote down'>\n";
    echo "                      <i class='icon-chevron-down'></i>\n";
    echo "                  </div><!--vote down-->\n";
    echo "              </div>\n";
    echo "          </div>\n";
    echo "      </article>\n";
    }
    ?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
    <article>
        <div id='title'><h1>Azért azt mondtam már hogy héjhó halihó, de igazából yolo, mert nem is igaz az, hogy ez tök gáz lenne.</h1></div>
        <div id='image'><img src='posts/2014-08-23/Screen Shot 2014-06-29 at 1.00.45 PM.png'></div>
        <div id='text' class='item' data-postid='52' data-score='0'>
            <p>Beküldte: zsombor
            <div class='vote-span'><!-- voting-->
                <div class='vote' data-action='up' title='Vote up'>
                    <i class='icon-chevron-up'></i>
                </div><!--vote up-->
                <div class='vote-score'>0</div>
                <div class='vote' data-action='down' title='Vote down'>
                    <i class='icon-chevron-down'></i>
                </div><!--vote down-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

But, when I inspect the resource it's not in index.php (of course) but only in an ajax.php file, which is appended to the index.php.

Here is the votingsys.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// ajax setup
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: '../vote.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: 'false'
});

// any voting button (up/down) clicked event
$('.vote').click(function(){
    var self = $(this); // cache $this
    var action = self.data('action'); // grab action data up/down 
    var parent = self.parent().parent(); // grab grand parent .item
    var postid = parent.data('postid'); // grab post id from data-postid
    var score = parent.data('score'); // grab score form data-score

    // only works where is no disabled class
    if (!parent.hasClass('.disabled')) {
        // vote up action
        if (action == 'up') {
            // increase vote score and color to orange
            parent.find('.vote-score').html(++score).css({'color':'orange'});
            // change vote up button color to orange
            self.css({'color':'orange'});
            // send ajax request with post id & action
            $.ajax({data: {'postid' : postid, 'action' : 'up'}});
        }
        // voting down action
        else if (action == 'down'){
            // decrease vote score and color to red
            parent.find('.vote-score').html(--score).css({'color':'red'});
            // change vote up button color to red
            self.css({'color':'red'});
            // send ajax request
            $.ajax({data: {'postid' : postid, 'action' : 'down'}});
        };
        // add disabled class with .item
        parent.addClass('.disabled');
    };
});
});
```

aaaand the vote.php file:

```
    include('config/connection.php');
    # start new session
    session_start();

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) {
if (isset($_POST['postid']) AND isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $postId = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postid']);
    # check if already voted, if found voted then return
    if (isset($_SESSION['vote'][$postId])) return;
    # connect mysql db
    dbConnect();

    # query into db table to know current voting score 
    $query = mysql_query("
        SELECT vote
        from posts
        WHERE id = '{$postId}' 
        LIMIT 1" );

    # increase or dicrease voting score
    if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($_POST['action'] === 'up'){
            $vote = ++$data['vote'];
        } else {
            $vote = --$data['vote'];
        }
        # update new voting score
        mysql_query("
            UPDATE posts
            SET vote = '{$vote}'
            WHERE id = '{$postId}' ");

        # set session with post id as true
        $_SESSION['vote'][$postId] = true;
        # close db connection
        dbConnect(false);
    }
}
}
?>
```

So is it possible to use another AJAX request like this or am I doing something really wrong?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.3.

Comment: Oh okay, I don't really know what's going on right now so take your time :)

Comment: Have you looked at your network monitor in your browser to watch the AJAX request kick off when you believe it should be happening? You need to ensure it starts (there may be a reason why the JavaScript code is not being run) and that the PHP replies with what you expect (there may be a problem on the server-side code, or the receiving of it in JavaScript may be faulty).

Comment: Also, check your browser console to see if you have any JavaScript errors. You can always do some simple file logging in your PHP side if you want to do tracing there too.

Comment: There's no JavaScript errors and the AJAX request just doesn't kick off. Also I might forgot tell you that I put the JavaScript including in the header as it should be there. Or should it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I bet I know what the problem is. You have five initial divs, which have click event handlers attached to them via this:

```
$('.vote').click(function(){ ... });
```

However, you are adding new divs via an infinite scroll device, and these do not have events attached to them. That is correct behaviour, since you are not re-running the code to attach them again.

There is a clever device in jQuery that will help you get around this. It lets you attach events to things now and in the future. To use it, try this:

```
$('container-selector').on('click', '.vote', function() { ... });
```

The `on` method with a 'click' parameter is just the new preferred way of attaching events in jQuery, and if you add your handler as a second parameter it will just do the same as now. However if you add the new parameter, `'.vote'`, it will attach the event to anything matching this *inside* the overall container selector, even if it did not exist at the time of attaching the event.

You can use `'body'` for the container selector here, but for performance reasons it is a good idea to be more specific than that. Just use whatever CSS selector will contain all of the divs to which you wish to attach this particular event handler.

Comment: I replaced the statement with yours but the only problem is I get a javascript error.
I replaced it like this: $('#main').on('click', '.vote', function(){ … });

and got this error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('main').on')

Comment: Am I using an older JQuery which doesn't recognise it ? I'm using JQuery 1.4.3

Comment: Of course, I already did and it works ! But somehow it drops me one error which is this : [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (vote.php, line 0)

Comment: Ah, if you get stuck with upgrading, it seems you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which was added in 1.4.2.

Comment: And according to phpMyadmin the query doesn't work, but that up to me now :)
Thanks for helping me out !

Comment: No problems - pleased to have helped! (The new error is a good sign - it means you are making progress. Debug that with your browser network monitor).